# How to share file with other apps in ionic

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I am trying to find a cordova plugin which will allow me to share a file with another app:

[image]

In iOS this, is a UIActivityViewController.  How do I do this in ionic cordova?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Cordova Social Sharing plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin) by Eddy Verbruggen.